# Default image's display doesn't change despite the source of the image changing.

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var allImages = [imageData, imageData1, imageData2, imageData3, imageData4];
    var count = 0; 

    $("#right").click(function() {
      if (count < 5){
      document.getElementById("hello").src = allImages[count];
      count++;
      }
    });
```

To explain this code, the array allImages contains base64 versions of 5 images. #hello is the ID of the default image. #right is the ID of a button.

So when I click #right, #hello's source is supposed to change to one of the images inside the allImages array. However, nothing happens to the display when I click #right.

I've tried changing the source outside of the right click function and when I do that, the display of #hello does correctly change. In addition to that, the #right click function does work cause i've stuck an alert inside of it before that activated upon click.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: do u use `data:image/(png,jpeg,..);base64,your_base64_data` as a src ?

Comment: So what *actually* happens? Is your `click` handler even called? Does `document.getElementById` actually return the element you expected? There isn't enough context here.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to check the value of **count** . 
It is quite possible that count being global variable some other block of code might have been updating it to some value leading `(count < 5) = false`.

**Suggestion** : Try after renaming the variable or by removing the if condition and setting some hard-coded value of src attribute

Comment: This is a wild guess at best.